# Rails testing has_many association failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, associations

I have 2 models. A `User` and a `Task`. Here's the code for them both:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :assigned_tasks, :class_name => 'Task', :foreign_key => 'assigned_user_id'
end
```

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :assigned_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'assigned_user_id'
end
```

The schema is quite obvious, but for consistency, this is how it looks:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110925050945) do
  create_table "tasks", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "assigned_user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

I've added a test case for the assigned_tasks relationship. It looks like this:

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "assigned tasks" do
    u1 = User.create(:name => 'john')
    u2 = User.create(:name => 'dave')

    assert_empty u2.assigned_tasks # LOOK AT ME

    task = u1.tasks.create(:name => 'some task', :assigned_user_id => u2.id)

    assert_equal 1, u2.assigned_tasks.size
  end
end
```

Now, this test case fails. It fails on the last assertion. If I remove the previous assertion (marked 'LOOK AT ME'), this test passes fine. It also passes fine if I change this line to `assert u2.assigned_tasks`. Meaning it appears to break when, and only when, `empty?` is called against `u2.assigned_tasks`. Where that assertion passes, the following one fails. Here's the failure:

```
UserTest:
     FAIL assigned tasks (0.12s) 
          <1> expected but was
<0>.
          test/unit/user_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

So, it appears once `empty?` is called on the original `u2.assigned_tasks` Array, the task is not actually added/associated with it's assigned user. This however appears to work fine in console.

Apologies if I'm completely overlooking something simple here, but I really can't make any sense of this. Any points in the right direction would be extremely helpful. Thanks

PS: Rails 3.1 with a vanilla application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reload the `assigned_tasks`, or `u2`.

```
# This line causes assigned_tasks to be loaded and cached on u2.  Not the calling
# of empty?, but rather the loading of the association.
assert_empty u2.assigned_tasks

# but then you actually make the task here
task = u1.tasks.create(:name => 'some task', :assigned_user_id => u2.id)

# so when this assertion happens, u2 already has an empty set of tasks cached, 
# and fails
assert_equal 1, u2.assigned_tasks.size

# however either of these should pass
assert_equal 1, u2.assigned_tasks(true).size
assert_equal 1, u2.reload.assigned_tasks.size
```

The `inverse_of` option serves to improve in-memory association behavior, and might also solve your problem (without reloading).  Read about that [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).  It would look something like this (but again I'm not positive it will work in this case):

```
# on User
has_many :assigned_tasks, ..., :inverse_of => :assigned_user

# on Task
belongs_to :assigned_user, ..., :inverse_of => :assigned_tasks

# in your test you might have to change the task creation to:
u1.tasks.create(:name => 'some task', :assigned_user => u2)
```

Comment: Oh snap, turns out I **was** just overlooking something simple. Thanks a lot, I sort of already knew about this, just completely overlooked it here. Also, your link is pointing to a youtube video

Comment: Ha!  Do you mean you didn't find any good info on rails associations in a video about the music of Faxanadu?  Oops :-P

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, I got at least a minute into the video before realizing you either mis(typed/pasted) or I was being trolled.. and that's embarrassing! :D